# Static build of curl with openssl: `/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found`

Tags: curl, openssl

This error looks like this is not static build - and OpenSSL not inside of curl, but after configure among others I see:
...
`SSL support:      enabled (OpenSSL)`
...
`Build libcurl:    Shared=no, Static=yes`

Git master, my commands:
`DFLAGS="-static" PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config --static" ./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --with-ssl`

`make curl_LDFLAGS=-all-static`

`sudo make install`

Comment: is OpenSSL also built and available as static on this system?

Comment: No, do I have to do this?

Comment: what happens when you build OpenSSL static (and probably also shared...) and then build curl static... ?